# Replace sha512 hash with sed via variable

Tags: bash, hash, sed

I'm using a code to create a sha512 hashed password.

```
source ~/xyz.cfg

test=$(python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; print sha512_crypt.encrypt('${XYZ_PASS}')")

sed 's/^"password.*$/"password" : "sha512|'$test'",/' /etc/xyz.json
```

${XYZ_PASS} is a password from another file and its stored hashed in test

But now the Problem:

The sha512 hash should replace another one:

Original line:
"password": "sha512|some-hash",

Line i want to sed into the file:

"password": "sha512|newshash",

newhash is the hash stored in test

The sed command doesn't work at all, I really have problems using it, im trying to get the solution for hours now.
best regards

Edit:
After this command

```
test=$(python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; print sha512_crypt.encrypt('${XYZ_PASS}')")
```

Test should (and does) contain a hash like this:

```
$6$rounds=60000$ca.5CQtZct/vKXxo$nu.wS1OSYo6dz02zvo9QJTkzz2TEg9stQF3OsOvauGCTu36P6463P3Cmpron6dwK.Dz7.RT2Az56f9NbEcw.g1
```

Edit:
https://github.com/Eugeny/ajenti/blob/master/config.json is the json
I'm trying to replace the password hash with my own

Comment: Your code, as is, works for me.  You need to show more details, such as what is actually in `$test`.  Are you sure that xyz.json has normal double quotes?  (Often, people creates files with editors that insert fancy unicode quotes that don't match the conventional `"`.)  Lastly, try `test=HELLO; echo '"password": "sha512|some-hash"' | sed 's/^"password.*$/"password" : "sha512|'$test'",/'`.  Does it work for you?

Comment: See Edit in the first Post

Comment: Injecting a shell variable into a Python program, even if that's a `python -c` one-liner, should be done via passing it on the argv or in the environment, **not** by substituting it into that Python program's source code: Putting data into source code is literally exactly what causes injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: ...which is to say that this is **severely** insecure: If your `XYZ_PASS` contained `'+__import__('os').system('rm -rf ~')+'`, you'd have a very, very bad day after running this code.

Comment: ...btw, if your goal is to edit a JSON file, consider using a JSON-aware tool. Python actually includes a JSON parsing/generation module, so you could use that with no additional dependencies; alternately, in the shell-programming world, what's perhaps the currently most popular tool for the job is `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: @John1024, ...if I could get your take, since the OP trusts you -- am I correct re: the injection vulnerability noted above?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues: (1) in the real json file, `"password"` is not at the beginning of the line, and (2) `test` contains `/` which is a sed-active character which needs to be escaped:

```
$ test='$6$rounds=60000$ca.5CQtZct/vKXxo$nu.wS1OSYo6dz02zvo9QJTkzz2TEg9stQF3OsOvauGCTu36‌​P6463P3Cmpron6dwK.Dz7.RT2Az56f9NbEcw.g1'
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]*"password.*$/"password" : "sha512|'"${test//\//\\/}"'",/' xyz.json
"password" : "sha512|$6$rounds=60000$ca.5CQtZct/vKXxo$nu.wS1OSYo6dz02zvo9QJTkzz2TEg9stQF3OsOvauGCTu36‌​P6463P3Cmpron6dwK.Dz7.RT2Az56f9NbEcw.g1",
```

Alternatively, consider using `awk` which avoids the escaping issues with `test`:

```
$ awk -v hash="$test" '$1~/^"password/{$0="   \"password\" : \"sha512|" hash "\","} 1' xyz.json
   "password" : "sha512|$6$rounds=60000$ca.5CQtZct/vKXxo$nu.wS1OSYo6dz02zvo9QJTkzz2TEg9stQF3OsOvauGCTu36‌​P6463P3Cmpron6dwK.Dz7.RT2Az56f9NbEcw.g1",
```

#### To save in-place

Using sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[[:space:]]*"password.*$/"password" : "sha512|'"${test//\//\\/}"'",/' xyz.json
```

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v hash="$test" '$1~/^"password/{$0="   \"password\" : \"sha512|" hash "\","} 1' xyz.json
```

Using BSD awk:

```
awk -v hash="$test" '$1~/^"password/{$0="   \"password\" : \"sha512|" hash "\","} 1' xyz.json >tmp.json && mv tmp.json xyz.json
```

Comment: In your real json file, the line does not start with `"password`.  Hence the regex `/^"password/` fails to match.  See updated answer.

Comment: Nevermind! 
The edited awk solution is working :) 
Thanks you saved my night!
SED is my personal nightmare

Comment: Hmm I'm using now:
awk -v hash="$test" '$1~/^"password/{$0="   \"password\" : \"sha512|" hash "\","} 1' /etc/ajenti/config.json

After running the command theres an output of the json file with the new password hash...
But it's not really saved in the json:
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/1d589d-1469665430.png

Comment: @Aeris See update for how to save the changed file in-place.

Comment: @Aeris I am not able to see the bilder-upload image because, currently, that website is [blocked for malware](http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php?search=www.bilder-upload.eu)

Comment: Huii merci, now it's working!
The Sed command is working too

PS:Sorry, I'm using this site for ages

Have a good night sir and thanks :)

Comment: I actually didn't know before reading this answer that gawk had in-place editing support; thank you for the lesson. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, a more secure way to call Python from shell (which doesn't let a maliciously-chosen password run arbitrary commands on your machine):

```
hash() {
  python -c 'import sys, passlib.hash; print passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.encrypt(sys.argv[1])' "$@"
}
```

---

Second, a more robust way to do the editing (with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)), that doesn't depend on details of how the file is formatted:

```
password_text="hello"
jq --arg hash "sha512|'$(hash "$password_text")'" \
  '.users.root.password=$hash' \
  <config.json >config.json.new
```

---

...or, even better, a way to do the whole thing in Python (using `os.environ`, a different secure method to pass data between processes without substituting it into code):

```
edit_password() {
  local infile outfile password
  case $# in
    3) infile=$1; outfile=$2; password=$3;;
    2) infile=$1; outfile=$1; password=$2;;
    *) echo "Usage: edit_password infile [outfile] password" >&2
       return 1
       ;;
  esac

  infile=$infile outfile=$outfile password=$password python <<'EOF'
import os, sys, passlib.hash, json

content = json.load(open(os.environ['infile'], 'r'))
new_value = "sha512|'%s'" % (passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.encrypt(os.environ['password']),)
content['users']['root']['password'] = new_value
json.dump(content, open(os.environ['outfile'], 'w'), indent=4)
EOF
}
```

...thereafter:

```
edit_password config.json my-config.json "new password"
```

...or, to edit in-place...

```
edit_password config.json "new password"
```

Comment: For both the secure python and the use of `jq`: +1